# How do you say 'the will to live' in Japanese?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

Can someone translate the English phrase, 'the will to live' into accurate Japanese? Is there an equivalent phrase in Japanese?

I've tried to translate each component separately:
Component 1 = the will = ishi
Component 2 = to live/to survive = seizon

So it becomes 'seizon no ishi'?

Can someone tell me if this is accurate? Or better yet, just give me the best translation you can come up with.

Oh, and it would be extremely helpful if someone can give me romaji version of the translation.

Thank you so much.

Comment: “Seizon” is used more often in the fact such as newspaper, the report and so on. Do you want to use it for  “Will to live”, the concept of schopenhauer, is translated into “ikiru ishi".

Comment: @kimiTanaka No, I suppose not. In fact, it has no philosophical bearing at all. I was merely looking for a phrase that means "the will to live" in the sense of "having the determination or spirit to survive/live”

Comment: I think as @kimiTanaka suggested, "ikiru ishi" 「生きる意志」 is the correct phrase for this, philosophical bearing or no.  生きる "ikiru" is the common verb for "to live" and as you already mentioned 意志 "ishi" is "will" or "volition" so the translation is directly "the will to live"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the interpretation in this text for "**a will to live**"?
It says that "**a will to live** or **the will to live**" is "生きる意欲 ***ikiru iyoku***"

> #### A Will to Live
>
> A: My aunt has joined a climbers' group. She is very strong-willed. She wants to climb the Matterhorn with the team.
>
> B: Really? But I heard she had lung cancer. When did she leave the hospice?
>
> A: She didn't. She hasn't recovered from the disease. It's supposed to be terminal, but the urge to climb the mountain has given her **the will to live**. This treatment is called "natural therapy"; no drugs or operations.

Source: 旺文社「英単語・熟語ダイアローグ１２００三訂版」

Comment: Yes‼‼ That's the context I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: This is a phrase I've never heard before, but I like it.